# Error importing tensorflow. unless you are using bazel, you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;

Tags: tensorflow

See the attached images for my python and tensorflow version.

[image]

[image]

Then I tested out importing tensorflow in cmd window.

```
$Python
>>> import tensorflow as tf
```

**But I get the following error:**

**Error:** Error importing tensorflow. unless you are using bazel, you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory; please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter from there

Comment: copy and format the text, do not insert images of text

Comment: ok. are you going to help or not?